# Need to remove arrow symbols from excel data

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I was given some data in excel and it looks like this:

Maps ix↵About the Author↵x↵Preface↵xi↵Ancillary

I need to remove these little arrows and replace them with a single white space. How would I do that?

Thank you.

Comment: Is this a one-time thing or are you trying to do this programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+`h` (Search and Replace), enter "↵" (by copy/paste) in the search field and  (blank space) in the replace field?

Comment: Yes I did indeed test it. That is I tested to paste the OPs string in a cell in Excel and then I did the copy/search/replace as described and it worked fine, as expected.

Comment: Thank you! That was a quick and simple solution. I haven't used excel much for this kind of thing so thank you!